# How to create a "Processing" page?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, javascript

Can someone tell me how to create to a "Please Wait" page.  When the pageload is complete, the default.aspx page shows up.  Is there a way to do that?  I do not want processing images or anything like that.  The actual page would be what I would want.

Comment: Is it the Page_Load of default.aspx that is hanging you up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I was looking for.  Sorry If I wasn't very clear, I tried.  I will do so next time.

[Click here](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20050108.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a detailed blog post about this a while back. The good news is it is detailed. The bad news is it is very old. It is before AJAX, though it uses JavaScript and touches on some of the things that have made AJAX big.

Also, it is for preventing users from clicking "Order" twice and thus causing a double-submit. That is close to what you want, but not exactly the same as what you asked for. However, I think the implementations would be similar.

[So, in case it helps, here it is. If it's too old, feel free to ignore it :)](http://www.charlieflowers.com/blog/archives/2006/09/solving_the_dou.html)

[Oh, and I forgot to mention there's a part 2, equally OLD, but telling how to make a base class for ASP.NET Page classes that all need this feature. Hope it helps in spite of its age.](http://www.charlieflowers.com/blog/archives/aspnet/index.html)

Comment: Looks like a winner.  Thanks, I will check into it.

Comment: Well good, hope it helps. But do keep in mind, it is old, and some things might be out of date.

Answer (score 0):

I use Panels frequently to do this.
This technique works if the processing is during a postback.

- User clicks button to begin processing.
- content area is in 1 panel, Processing window is in another panel.
- on click on processing button, Processing panel displayed, other panel hidden.
- separate thread processes records, or ajax call on page calls the actual processing routine.
- on end of processing routine, go to results page, or display results data.

You could use similar logic for a in-page popup screen or popup image.